# NameError: name 'rotor' is not defined

Tags: anaconda, python-module

I try to import and run selfmade modules under Spyder.
The main.py programm

```
    import rot
    f=rotor(b_x,b_y,b_z,x,y,z)
```

The rot.py programm

```
    def rotor(bx,by,bz,x,y,z):
        import numpy as np
        ...
```

The issue is:

File "C:\Users\Professional.spyder-py3\my_pro\jgut\main.py", line 93, in 
    f=rotor(b_x,b_y,b_z,x,y,z)

NameError: name 'rotor' is not defined

Problem doesn't disappear even after starting brut force start of any imported modules.
Is there a way to start all imported modules simultaniously? Or maybesomeone faced this problem?

P.S. Problem appeared today after Anaconda reinstall, becouse of incopatebilities with IK-Multimedia apps (I just removed them). I was starting all the mudules by brut force from the begining.

Comment: I edited the question because this has nothing to do with Spyder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Please, do not import modules in functions!

2) `rotor` is not defined because it is in the `rot` namespace. You can call it by `rot.rotor(args)`. If you wanted to do call it the way you do, you have to import it like this: `from rot import rotor` or `from rot import *` (which imports everything from the rot module and is a bad practise - you should only import what you need).

The error has nothing to do with anything written in the last 2 paragraphs.

Comment: It works, thanks. But I cann't understand appeared problem fully. If I import numpy as np I have an access to all of numpy functions and it works well. What goes wrong when modules of mine are loaded? Is numpy designed in some other way?

Comment: If you `import numpy as np`, the numpy namespace is then reffered to as `np` and you call all the numpy functions with the `np.` prefix. If you instead wrote only `import numpy`, you'd have to call every numpy function with the `numpy.` prefix.